# שישי or ששי - two yuds or one?

Tags: talmud-gemara, number

The Shas Vilna Hachadash for Yevamos writes שישי with two yuds at the top of each page for the sixth perek yet writes ששי with only one yud for the Meforshim commentating on the sixth perek in the later pages of the Gemara. Why the difference?

Comment: It's spelled deficiently throughout Tanach

Comment: Honestly, it's probably just one of those things.